# What is the time complexity of this simple sequential graph coloring code?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, time-complexity, complexity-theory

The code bellow tries to solve the graph coloring problem (k-coloring). I'm really struggling to find its time complexity.
It's basically three nested loops. In worst case:

1. Outermost loop runs len(graph) (the size of a given graph - its number of vertices) times.
2. Inner for loop runs num_colors times (number of colors being tested)
3. Innermost loop, which comes from neighbors_have_different_colors function, runs "the number of adjacent vertices" times for each vertex in the graph.

I have a guess that it is O(n*k^x), for n being the graph size, k being the number of colors being tested and x being the maximum degree of the graph, but I'm not sure about it.

```
def try_coloring(graph, num_colors):
    assert num_colors >= 0, "Invalid number of colors: %s" % num_colors
    colors = {}
 
    def neighbors_have_different_colors(nodes, color):
        #returns true if the color is not present in the adjacent vertices
        return all(color != colors.get(n) for n in nodes)
 
    #code bellow is all about checking if the condition above is true
    #for each node in the graph and for each "color" up to num_colors
    #if it gets to num_color without finding a color, the graph is not "k-colorable"
    for node, adjacents in graph.items():
        found_color = False
        for color in range(num_colors):
            if neighbors_have_different_colors(adjacents, color):
                found_color = True
                colors[node] = color
                break
 
        if not found_color:
            return None
    return colors
```

Comment: How do you argue for the `k^x` part? My first intuition would have been `O(nkx)`

Comment: Looks like `O(n*k*x)` to me. Also, the comment that *"if it gets to num_color without finding a color, the graph is not "k-colorable""* is not true. [The algorithm the code uses is a greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring), and is not guaranteed to find the minimum number of colors for the graph. So the graph may be k-colorable even when the algorithm fails.

Comment: @LoneLunatic I'm thinking of an recursion tree. Every vertex compare with their adjacent n times. So, there's gotta be a expontential there. Maybe O((k*x)^n) ?

Comment: @user3386109 
"the graph may be k-colorable even when the algorithm fails"
Still haven't found that case